# Where should I find the fish_add_path command?

Tags: command-line, snap, fish

After a system updated my fish shell prompt is no longer working. Whenever I open a terminal I get this error:

```
/usr/share/fish/vendor_conf.d/snapd.fish (line 3): 
fish_add_path -aP $snap_bin_path
^
from sourcing file /usr/share/fish/vendor_conf.d/snapd.fish
    called on line 294 of file /usr/share/fish/config.fish
from sourcing file /usr/share/fish/config.fish
    called during startup
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type `help` for instructions on how to use fish
```

I have confirmed that `fish_add_path` is cannot be invoked from the command line, which surprises me because [it's one of the essential helper functions included in fish](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/fish_add_path.html).

Other relevant details:

```
~> snap --version
snap    2.54.2+20.04ubuntu2
snapd   2.54.2+20.04ubuntu2
series  16
ubuntu  20.04
kernel  5.13.0-28-generic
~> fish --version
fish, version 3.1.0
~> which fish
/usr/bin/fish
~> echo $PATH
/home/user/.amplify/bin /home/user/.local/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin /usr/games /usr/local/games /snap/bin /home/user/.local/bin
```

...so /snap/bin is on the `$PATH` anyway.

I'm assuming an update to fish and/or snap triggered this error. Assuming a clean installation of fish on Ubuntu, where *should* I find the **fish_add_path** tool?

Comment: The page you linked is for fish 3.3.1 - according to the [release notes](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/relnotes.html), `fish_add_path` was added in fish 3.2.0 ... you appear to be using fish 3.1.0

Comment: FWIW, I'm having the same issue. Fish installed thru `apt`, running 3.1.0. Commenting out the line in `/usr/share/fish/vendor_conf.d/snapd.fish` does hide the error

Comment: I'm guessing a snap update assumes a newer version of fish than available in LTS

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You might be thinking of `set -U fish_user_paths` from earlier versions of fish. `fish_add_path` [was added in fish 3.2.0](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/relnotes.html) but you are running fish 3.1.0.

You can upgrade to the latest version of fish (3.3.1) from a PPA as follows:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fish-shell/release-3
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

This is the PPA linked to from the official fish homepage. Based on the information on the [3.x release series page](https://launchpad.net/%7Efish-shell/+archive/ubuntu/release-3), this should work for the bionic, focal, groovy, hirsute, and xenial versions of Ubuntu.

Running these commands resolved this issue the next time I opened a fish shell.

---

Alternatively, you can comment out the relevant line in `/usr/share/fish/vendor_conf.d/snapd.fish`. It appears that [snap assumes you are running a newer version of fish](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1957948).

Comment: I can confirm that this fixed the issue for me

Comment: This fixed the issue for me too. Before upgrading, I had the 3.1.0 version of fish that came with the default Ubuntu 20.04 repo. After upgrading, I had fish 3.3.1 and `fish_add_path` is available on my PATH, which fixes the issue.

Comment: Also, remember that there's another bug affecting that file: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1957155; if you don't fix it, you get all kind of malfunctioning in GUI applications (meld crashes with SIGTRAP, Kompare doesn't start, stuff like that).